# Java plugin is not detected in Firefox browser

Tags: java, plugins

I installed the latest version of Java plugin on Windows 10, everything is enabled, but when I proceed to verify it on `java.com/verify` it says: *"Java is disabled or not installed "*

Where is the problem?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://java.com/en/download/help/firefox_java.xml

Comment: Firefox ESR 52 version supports Java...but firefox removed that version too from their support. You may need to change the browser. You can use IE9,10,11 etc. But,IE-Edge doesn't support Java.

Answer (score 1):

I got Java plugin in Firefox all figured out (it was a lot of fun as all these hurtles to it in these times).

1. "Firefox 51.0.1" or "Firefox 52.9.0esr" either "win32" or "linux-i686" (or "win32-EME-free") the last to support Java applets.
2. "EME" just means "Play DRM content" is NOT checked by default (that's it - just "win32" plus uncheck that is same).
3. Installing an "old Firefox" is an "auto update problem" so install w/o Internet then check "Never check for updates (not recommended: security risk)".
4. "Mozilla Maintenance Service" should be installed if using "Windows 10" even if "NOT want updates" (or else it bugs you about it on each startup).
5. To totally uninstall Firefox in "Windows 10" you "uninstall" PLUS manually delete all "Mozilla Firefox" folders (also is registry but not too important).
6. Installing Java you MAY (say in JDK 1.6) get "jre\bin\new_plugin\npjp2.dll" as your "Java applet plugin" but how to "tell Firefox about it"?
7. Oracle and Mozilla saying "NPAPI and/or Java is a security risk" you now use a "MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH" environment variable to do that (in "Windows 10").
8. Not sure how all "Firefox searches for plugins" but in the past or future lots of "URLs" if go into "about:config" (in Firefox's URL text field).
9. If you have or get a "plugins" folder or find "pluginreg.dat" that is just misdirection (use the "MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH" environment variable not those two).
10. Also you have to go into "about:config" (in Firefox's URL text field) find "extensions.blocklist.enabled" and toggle it to "false" (very important).
11. If you do NOT do that you get "Your browser understands the APPLET tag but isn't running the applet" trying to run JDK applet demos.
12. Not too much "Java applet security risk" if go "Add-ons" to "Plugins" to say "Ask to Activate" and only "use applets YOU trust"?
13. You do want "Firefox latest" to get "best JavaScript security" though and "backup plus restore" is always your "best security to count on"?
14. NOTE: using Mozilla Firefox on Linux tends to be easier but should be a "symbolic link" in a "plugins folder" to your "Java applet plugin".

Comment: Your answer answers nothing.

Comment: @extensa5620 - not true, out of tons of google hits, this is where i found the obscure missing piece about "MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH" that makes the plugin actually show up in firefox when you've done everything else typically recommended... i know we're not supposed to, but thank you @JUser!

Answer (score -3):

In the latest version of the Firefox Browser(Windows-64 Bit), it does not recognize or support the Java plugin. It's not a huge problem however as Google has already done this to their popular Chrome Browser.

[Java plugin in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-java-plugin-to-view-interactive-content)

If you are using a different version of Firefox than the one I listed, then you may want to check to see that you have Java enabled in Firefox.